# Where downloaded file name set?

Tags: java, liferay, liferay-6, portal

I have some code to download pdf file like below way:

```
byte[] text = textContent.getText();
InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(text );
response.setContentType("application/pdf");
ServletResponseUtil.write(response, inputStream);
```

File has downloaded successfully with some name but where does that names come from?

Comment: Can you add the original file name and the downloaded file name? Don't need to be exact, but at least "this-File-Name" to "another_File_name"?

Comment: When i perform some action the file as pdf got donloaded with somename Here I cant figure it out where that name set.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the filename in the response header.

```
response.setContentType("application/pdf");
response.addProperty("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + myFilename);
```

The assumption here is that the resource is served during the resource phase of a portlet.

For full list of `Content-Disposition` options, see [RFC 6266](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6266).

As long as there is no `Content-Disposition` header, the browser will derive the file name from the request URL.

Comment: I would like to add that [RFC 6266](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6266) defines some more options - like `inline` instead of `attachment` - which should serve as further reference.

Comment: Thanks, I included the RFC 6266 link in the answer.

Comment: I included the information about the original file name, as this was a question as well from the OP.